# SQL, multiply two columns in the same row and create a "total" column

Tags: sql, multiple-columns

[image]

That is what I am trying to achieve, I have everything except for the Total column. The total column be the result of the Number * Product Price. I have tried several sum() queries, but none are coming out the way I want and finding it difficult making this new column in the process. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Just multiply the fields, like `Number * Price AS Total`.

Comment: Please, formatted text - not images.

Answer (score 4):

**You should be able to simply append it to your query like so:**

```
SELECT TransactionID,
       CustomerID,
       StoreID,
       TransactionDate,
       Number,
       ProductName,
       ProductPrice,
       Number*ProductPrice AS Total
FROM dbo.table
```